# Sandcastle isignoring my invalid XML comments file Due to some bad HTMLin a MS compoent

Tags: .net, sandcastle

I am using the latest version of Sandcastle to document my project. The help file is missing loads of content and I have this error in my log:

```
Ignoring invalid XML comments file '\System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.xml'.  Reason: The 'br' start tag on line 977 position 39 does not match the end tag of 'p'.
```

Looking at that file when it is created I see this XML fragment:

```
<member name="P:System.Configuration.SectionInformation.ForceSave">
      <summary>Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the associated configuration section will be saved even if it has not been modified.</summary>
      <returns><p sourcefile="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.yml" sourcestartlinenumber="1" sourceendlinenumber="3"><p sourcefile="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.yml" sourcestartlinenumber="1" sourceendlinenumber="1"><code>true</code> if the associated <xref href="System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection"></xref> object will be saved even if it has not been modified; otherwise, <code>false</code>. The default is <code>false</code>.  </p>
 <block subset="none" type="note"><p>**<br>** If the configuration file is saved (even if there are no modifications), ASP.NET restarts the application.  </p>
<p sourcefile="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.yml" sourcestartlinenumber="5" sourceendlinenumber="5"></block></p>
</returns>
    </member>
```

Intellisense in Visual Studio highlights issues with the <br> tag which I believe should be a <br/>.

Two questions - how can I work around this in my help file as this is MS supplied content?

The online page for the MS content is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.sectioninformation.forcesave?view=netframework-4.8

Where can I report this to Microsoft?

Comment: In the upper right hand corner of many ms document pages there is an edit button that lets you suggest content changes.  You are talking about content and runtime here at the same time but the comment tool might be a start.

Comment: Thanks for that (and realise I am talking both content and tooling) - I have looked at the page I  linked to and curiously it doesn't have the <br>. tag but a <para> one! So there must be a higher source!